# Can I omit node_modules from Azure mobile services repo?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm writing an Windows Azure Mobile Services background job.  If I use node.js modules other than the defaults provided by Azure, can I omit the node_modules folder when committing to my Azure git repo if I have a root package.json?  Will Azure download those packages automatically?

Update: For clarification, I have the following repo (sorry, this is from memory, don't have it in front of me)

```
> <root repo dir>    
>     \service
>       \api
>       \scheduler
>          \node_modules
>            \npmmodule1
>            \npmmodule2 .. etc
>          package.json <-- generated with npm init
>          myJob.js
```

I'm asking if the following is sufficient for commit and deploy

```
> <root repo dir>    
>   \service
>       \api
>       \scheduler
>          package.json <-- generated with npminit
>          myJob.js
```

Comment: I can't see why not? It seems to me that this is more a question of should node modules be omitted from your repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Currently, Azure Mobile Services does not pull the any modules from NPM based on the presence of a `package.json` file. You need to `npm install` the modules in your local Git clone, `git add` the `node_modules` folder in your repository and push the changes to the server.

Supporting npm package restore (via package.json) is a feature which is in the backlog to be implemented. I'd suggest you create a feature request on the [Azure Mobile Services UserVoice](http://mobileservices.uservoice.com), so it can be prioritized accordingly.

Comment: Is this the same? Or does it just allow for use of modules from node_modules which is committed to the repo?: http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/3338408-npm-support

Comment: Yes, that's part of it. The first part has already been implemented (npm support). The second part (specify specific version) works for modules which you install yourself (via npm) but not for modules which are already installed in the runtime. Can you please add a comment to that request detailing your issue, so it will be addressed when the feature is fully implemented? Thanks!

Comment: just to clarify for myself, the current state of affairs is that there is support for 3rd party modules installed via NPM and committed to the repo, but no automatic download during deployment based on package.json.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you couldn't have put it better.

Comment: Thanks, great feedback.  Here is my UserVoice entry by the way: http://bit.ly/19ZlUFz